# Merging a specific column from multiple text files into one file

Tags: python

I have multiple folders and a text file (`input.txt`) in each folder. First I read the folder names from `f_names.txt`, then enter into each folder and read the third column from the `input.txt` in each folder. The code works properly until here. The problem is that the code merges all the third columns in a row in output file (`combine.txt`). Whereas I want to write each third column to the output file (`combine.txt`) as a new column. How can I do this?

**Here is my code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import re

path=os.getcwd()

try:
    os.remove("combine.txt")
except OSError:
    pass

with open('combine.txt', mode='a') as outfile:
    with open('f_names.txt', 'r') as read_f:
        for line in read_f:
            os.chdir(line.strip())
            with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
                data=[]
                for line in f:
                    row = line.split()
                    data.append(float(row[2]))
                    outfile.write("%.2f\n" % float(row[2]))
            os.chdir("..")
```

**Obtained output (for two input files):**

```
2.12
3.15
4.18
8.45
2.10
0.12
0.18
0.32
0.21
0.13
```

**Desired output (for two input files):**

```
2.12 0.12
3.15 0.18
4.18 0.32
8.45 0.21
2.10 0.13
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some things that you can do to make your program correct and "more pythonic."

```
with open('f_names.txt') as read_f:
    # Collect the third columns in a list
    data = []
    for line in read_f:
        # No need to chdir()
        with open('{}/input.txt'.format(line.strip())) as f:
            # This is one column
            data.append([float(line.split()[2]) for line in f])

# Do not remove the old file, overwrite it
with open('combine.txt', 'w') as outfile:    
    # "Transpose" the list of columns into a list of rows
    # Write each row
    for row in zip(*data):
        # Use new-style formatting
        outfile.write(" ".join("{:.2f}".format(cell) for cell in row) + "\n")
```

Comment: Thanks. There are also two lines starting with `@`  and `#`symbols in each `input.txt` file. How can I exclude those lines in each input file?